# months_between for a leap year

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

When I find months between 28-FEB-11 and 29-FEB-12, months_between function in oracle returns 12. Actually it should be 12.096. This function is not calculating for the leap year proper.

For between 28-FEB-11 and 29-FEB-12, it is 1 year(12 months) and 1 day.

```
      select months_between('28-FEB-12', '28-FEB-11') from dual; -- 12
      **select months_between('29-FEB-12', '28-FEB-11') from dual; -- 12**
      select months_between('28-FEB-12', '27-FEB-11') from dual; -- 12.0322
      select months_between('27-FEB-12', '28-FEB-11') from dual; -- 11.9677
```

is this an Oracle bug??..

-Vishwa

Comment: You could easily have answered this question for yourself by reading the documentation.  Oracle's documentation is online, comprehensive and free.  You should learn how to use it.  http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/homepage

Answer (score 5):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions102.htm#i78039):

> MONTHS_BETWEEN returns number of months between dates date1 and date2. If date1 is later than date2, then the result is positive. If date1 is earlier than date2, then the result is negative. If date1 and date2 are either the same days of the month or both last days of months, then the result is always an integer. Otherwise Oracle Database calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month and considers the difference in time components date1 and date2.

So it's following the documented behavior. It's just not what you expected.

Comment: In other words, `months_between('30-APR-12', '31-JUL-12')` is excatly `3`.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a bug because ORACLE says so, it's a logical error driven by a human (and documenting as something rigth) which is worse.

How come if difference between the last days of January and February months is exactly 1 month (29 exact days). Please see below:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN('29-FEB-12','31-JAN-12')
1
```

With an extra day (30 days) the difference in months is less than 1. Please see below:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN('29-FEB-12','30-JAN-12')
.967741935
```

WRONG. That's not rigth at all!

SQL Server in another hand handle this correctly:

```
select DATEDIFF(MM,'29-FEB-12','30-JAN-12')
select DATEDIFF(MM,'29-FEB-12','31-JAN-12')
```

both are 1

Comment: Most likely, SQL Server is getting the same value, just rounding to an integer.